# Creating two outer classes in one .cls file

Tags: apex

I am trying this piece of code on one .cls file and I will be instantiating the OuterClass2 inside OuterClass1. What could be reason for getting a  **Missing '' at 'public' error** just on the beginning line of OuterClass2.

```
public with sharing class OuterClass1{
    //declarations here
    OuterClass2 oc = new OuterClass2();
}

public class OuterClass2 {
   @AuraEnabled @InvocableVariable(required=true)
    public Integer Order;
    
    @AuraEnabled @InvocableVariable(required=true)
    public String Name;
}
```

I also want to use the OuterClass2 as an Apex-Defined data type for flows as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't have two outer classes in a single file. Move `OuterClass2` into `OuterClass2.cls`.

Classes do not need to be in the same file to reference one another.

Answer (score 6):

A single apex class file can only have one top-level (outer) class.

You can declare classes inside of an outer class (which would make it an "inner" class). Disregarding naming for a bit...

```
public with sharing class OuterClass1{
    //declarations here
    OuterClass2 oc = new OuterClass2();

    public class OuterClass2 {
        @AuraEnabled @InvocableVariable(required=true)
        public Integer Order;
    
        @AuraEnabled @InvocableVariable(required=true)
        public String Name;
    }
}
```

would compile.

To reference `OuterClass2` outside of this class, you use `<outer class>.<inner class>`. E.g. `OuterClass1.OuterClass2 oc2Instance = new OuterClass1.OuterClass2();`