# Unexpected token 'Boolean'

Tags: trigger, data, data-types, boolean, private

Hey guys I'm new to Apex and even pretty new to Java, It's probably a stupid mistake but I can't figure it out. I am getting "Unexpected token 'boolean'." error , tried with both Boolean and boolean and its the same error. Can anyone help?

```
private boolean isValidCreditCardNumber(String creditCardNumber) {
    Integer sum = 0;
    boolean isDouble = false;
    for (Integer i = creditCardNumber.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        Integer digit = Integer.valueOf(creditCardNumber.substring(i, i + 1));
        if (isDouble) {
            digit = digit * 2;
            if (digit > 9) {
                digit = digit - 9;
            }
        }
        sum = sum + digit;
        isDouble = !isDouble;
    }
    return (sum / 10 == 0);
}
trigger ValidateCreditCardNumber on Contact (before update) {
    // Loop through each Contact record in the trigger
    for (Contact c : Trigger.new) {
        // Check if the Credit Card Number field has been updated
        if (c.Credit_Card_Number__c != Trigger.oldMap.get(c.Id).Credit_Card_Number__c) {
            // Validate the Credit Card Number using the Luhn algorithm
            if (!isValidCreditCardNumber(c.Credit_Card_Number__c)) {
                c.Credit_Card_Number__c.addError('Credit Card Number is not valid. Please enter a valid number.');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Edit: I changed it to the follow and the error is gone but now im getting a different error. Missing '' at 'trigger'

```
public class CreditCardValidator {
    public static Boolean isValidCreditCardNumber(String creditCardNumber) {
        Integer sum = 0;
        boolean isDouble = false;
        for (Integer i = creditCardNumber.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            Integer digit = Integer.valueOf(creditCardNumber.substring(i, i + 1));
            if (isDouble) {
                digit = digit * 2;
                if (digit > 9) {
                    digit = digit - 9;
                }
            }
            sum = sum + digit;
            isDouble = !isDouble;
        }
        return (sum / 10 == 0);
    }
}
trigger ValidateCreditCardNumber on Contact (before update) {
    // Loop through each Contact record in the trigger
    for (Contact c : Trigger.new) {
        // Check if the Credit Card Number field has been updated
        if (c.Credit_Card_Number__c != Trigger.oldMap.get(c.Id).Credit_Card_Number__c) {
            // Validate the Credit Card Number using the Luhn algorithm
            if (!isValidCreditCardNumber(c.Credit_Card_Number__c)) {
                c.Credit_Card_Number__c.addError('Credit Card Number is not valid. Please enter a valid number.');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi. I'm not sure, but getting the impression your code snippet is actually the content of a single file and that your `isValidCreditCardNumber` method is outside of a class?

Comment: Yep you're right I changed it and now I'm getting "Missing EOF at trigger" error

Comment: Don't put a class and a trigger in the same file.

Comment: I suspected that was the issue, like I said its probably something big that im missing haha. Thanks anyway Felix and Phil as well.

Comment: You might like to watch [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GHIX-wesizI) about SFDX. You'll find some info about metadata format and source format from around 19 minutes in. This is from when the "source format" was first introduced - I would recommend always using source format regardless. All that said, there's no explicit official documentation listing content of the various files (classes and triggers). You might find [this other Q&A](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/388096/creating-two-outer-classes-in-one-cls-file) helpful.